# nestjs module is not injected properly

Tags: typescript, graphql, nestjs

I created new module in nest using the command `nest g module UserModule`

`src/user-module/user.resolver.ts` is -

```js
import { Query, Resolver } from '@nestjs/graphql';
import { UserService } from './user.service';

export class UserResolver {
  
  constructor (private readonly user: UserService) {
   this.user = user; 
  }

  @Query('users')
  async users() {
    return this.user.getUsers();
  }
}
```

then `src/user-module/user-module.module.ts` is -

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { UserResolver } from './user.resolver';
import { UserService } from './user.service';
import { PrismaService } from './prisma.services';

@Module({
  providers: [UserResolver, UserService, PrismaService]
})

export class UserModuleModule {}
```

the file `src/user-module/user.service.ts` -

```js
import { Injectable } from "@nestjs/common";
import { PrismaService } from "./prisma.services";
import { User } from "src/graphql";

@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  constructor(private readonly prisma: PrismaService) {

  }

  async getUsers(): Promise<User[]> {
    return this.prisma.prismaUsers.findMany({})
  }
}
```

the `src/user-module/prisma.services.ts` -

```js
import { Injectable, OnModuleInit } from '@nestjs/common';
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client';

@Injectable()
export class PrismaService extends PrismaClient implements OnModuleInit {
  async onModuleInit() {
    await this.$connect();
  }
}
```

I started the service with `npm start`. I queried the service using below command -

```
query {
   users {
     id
     name
     email
   }
}
```

[image: graphql error]

I get the below error -

> [Nest] 24682  - 09/09/2023, 10:59:34 AM   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] Cannot read properties of undefined (reading'getUsers')
> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getUsers')
> at UserResolver.users (/home/raj/Coding/ts/prisma-gql-express-demo/src/user-module/user.resolver.ts:12:22)
> at /home/raj/Coding/ts/prisma-gql-express-demo/node_modules/@nestjs/core/helpers/external-context-creator.js:69:29
> at InterceptorsConsumer.intercept (/home/raj/Coding/ts/prisma-gql-express-demo/node_modules/@nestjs/core/interceptors/interceptors-consumer.js:12:20)
> at target (/home/raj/Coding/ts/prisma-gql-express-demo/node_modules/@nestjs/core/helpers/external-context-creator.js:74:60)
> at Object.users (/home/raj/Coding/ts/prisma-gql-express-demo/node_modules/@nestjs/core/helpers/external-proxy.js:9:30)
> at field.resolve (/home/raj/Coding/ts/prisma-gql-express-demo/node_modules/@apollo/server/src/utils/schemaInstrumentation.ts:82:22)
> at executeField (/home/raj/Coding/ts/prisma-gql-express-demo/node_modules/graphql/execution/execute.js:492:20)
> at executeFields (/home/raj/Coding/ts/prisma-gql-express-demo/node_modules/graphql/execution/execute.js:414:22)
> at executeOperation (/home/raj/Coding/ts/prisma-gql-express-demo/node_modules/graphql/execution/execute.js:344:14)
> at execute (/home/raj/Coding/ts/prisma-gql-express-demo/node_modules/graphql/execution/execute.js:136:20)

What is wrong with my injection and why it is not working ?
my complete code is here in [github](https://github.com/rajcspsg/prisma-gql-express-demo/blob/main/src/user-module/prisma.services.ts).
I seen this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58436968/nestjs-module-not-injecting-dependency-to-its-resolver) but my error seems to be due to different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `UserResolver` class needs to have `@Resolver()` decorating it, so that Nest knows it's a resolver and so Typescript knows to emit the type metadata in the constructor for the class. It's just like needing to add `@Injectable()` to a regular provider, it tells Typescript to emit the metadata